# Are there guidelines for starting the emulators in a memory-constrained container?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I am trying to start the firebase emulator suite (mostly firestore) on my rather memory-constrained dev environment. It is a Steam deck running ubuntu in a container via distrobox. I apparently have 16 Gb of ram, 16 Gb of swap, and have set max heap size to 6Gb via JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

When I start the emulators from scratch, everything is fine. The functions and rules emulators load no problem. But if i append `--import some_backup` where some_backup is a snapshot of a live firestore database, fans start whirring, java hits 600% CPU utilization, I run out of memory, and importantly, nothing ever loads in the emulator web ui, it just spins for a while, gives up. On my laptop (64 GB ram) it takes a little while to start up (~10 sec?) and then works fine. Laptop has a beefier CPU as well, but the CPU in a steam deck isn't bad.

The live snapshot is about 750 MB. It is not huge by any stretch of the imagination.

My hypothesis is that some process deep in the emulator is either thrashing and taking too long, or getting killed for exceeding heap limits. Again, why it takes 6Gb to load 750 Mb of data is a bit surprising, but I understand how these things work, the 750 mb may just be compressed storage and I am pretty sure the raw data in the database is pretty compressible.

ANYWAY. The actual questions I have are:

1. has anyone tuned the firestore emulator to run in low RAM scenarios?
2. if not, is there a log / thread dump file created by default by the actual emulator java processes? I'm not seeing any good error messages on the default stdout / stderr when i start the emulators, but I have not looked to see if there are any high-verbosity flags either.
3. yes, i have a laptop, but this is a side project and I wanted to see if I could do a little dev work while I travel without having to take a whole laptop if I was already bringing the steam deck.

Comment: Aha yeah- I found the --debug flag to pass to the CLI, and that shows ` {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"\nException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread \"HTTP-Dispatcher\"\n"}}` after a while. I'll try to bump up the max heap a bit more and see where I get.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out.

1. use the --debug flag to get better error messages from firebase's runtime.
2. bump the max heap even more. I have no idea why a 750 MB file needs 16 GB of heap, but when let java go that high (`export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx16g`) I can load the dataset.

Kind of thrashes the system to swapfiles, but swap on an nvme sdd is pretty fast. The emulator seems to consistently eat about 14 Gb of the real memory I have. So, feasible but I suspect there's room for improvement in there.